# SQLAlchemy, what is the best way to select values in a tables column with date ranges that are in the range of another tables set of dates?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an example Costs table below of custom costs with date ranges as well as an Orders table with date_created column. I am trying to select the cost if it is in the range of an Orders.date_created date. The Orders.date_created range changes depending on the range selected.

| cost | date_min | date_max | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | Once |
| 200 | 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | Once |
| 5 | 2019-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | Weekly |

I have the following in python with flask-sqlalchemy:

```py
limit = db.session.query(
        db.func.count(Costs.id.distinct()).label('count')
    ).filter(
        Costs.frequency == 'Once'
    ).filter(and_(
        Orders.date_created.between(Costs.date_min, Costs.date_max)
    )).scalar()

custom_single_cost = db.session.query(
        Costs.cost
    ).filter(
        Costs.frequency == 'Once'
    ).filter(and_(
        Orders.date_created.between(Costs.date_min, Costs.date_max)
    )).limit(limit)
```

It seems to work but is there a more simple or quicker way to solve this problem as I then have to sum with python the total rather than use SQL via sqlalchemy which may be quicker as I could have alot of custom inputs with various date ranges?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it.  I just needed to sum the distinct cost.

```py
custom_single_cost = db.session.query(
        db.func.sum(Costs.cost.distinct()).label('single_cost')
    ).filter(
        Costs.frequency == 'Once'
    ).filter(and_(
        Orders.date_created.between(Costs.date_min, Costs.date_max)
    )).all()
```